# How to average a block of numbers separated by null in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Given is the following pyspark dataframe, where the order is given by ID:

| ID | age |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | null |
| 2 | 10 |
| 3 | 90 |
| 4 | null |
| 5 | null |
| 6 | null |
| 7 | 20 |
| 8 | 30 |
| 9 | 70 |
| 10 | null |

I need to create the average over blocks of consecutive numbers separated by null. Thus, I aim for the following data frame:

| FirstID | Last_ID | avg_age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 3 | 50 |
| 7 | 9 | 40 |

- Using a window with a specified `rangeBetween` didn't work, as it averaged the first and second block.
- I also tried creating a new column `non-null-block` indicating non-null age, but in order to perform the necessary aggregation, I would need to assign unique numbers block by block - like so:

| ID | age | non-null-block |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | null |
| 2 | 10 | 1 |
| 3 | 90 | 1 |
| 4 | null | null |
| 5 | null | null |
| 6 | null | null |
| 7 | 20 | 2 |
| 8 | 30 | 2 |
| 9 | 70 | 2 |
| 10 | null | null |

Which sounds like the very same problem I already have - and may also indicate, why I got also stuck with this.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `lag` to check whether the previous row is null, and if the current row is not null, you can flag that as the start of a block. After that, sum the flags and you'll get the block number that you wanted.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'block',
    (~F.col('age').isNull() & F.lag('age').over(Window.orderBy('ID')).isNull()).cast('int')
).withColumn(
    'block',
    F.when(~F.col('age').isNull(), F.sum('block').over(Window.orderBy('ID')))
)

df2.show()
+---+----+-----+
| ID| age|block|
+---+----+-----+
|  1|null| null|
|  2|  10|    1|
|  3|  90|    1|
|  4|null| null|
|  5|null| null|
|  6|null| null|
|  7|  20|    2|
|  8|  30|    2|
|  9|  70|    2|
| 10|null| null|
+---+----+-----+
```

Then you can do the aggregation:

```
df3 = (df2.filter('block is not null')
          .groupBy('block')
          .agg(F.min('ID').alias('First_ID'), F.max('ID').alias('Last_ID'), F.avg('age').alias('avg_age'))
          .drop('block')
      )

df3.show()
+--------+-------+-------+
|First_ID|Last_ID|avg_age|
+--------+-------+-------+
|       2|      3|   50.0|
|       7|      9|   40.0|
+--------+-------+-------+
```